# NSDate confusion dateFromString format

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

```
//Grab current day from sys date all I am interested in is the day i.e 01 - 31 days of month
NSDateFormatter *dayFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dayFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd"];
NSString *dayString = [dayFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Later on in my code i then want to convert this string dayString to NSDate like below but dayFromString however the format is not just day the log is 2000-01-16 00:00:00 +0000 all i want is the 16

```
NSDate *dayFromString = [dayFormatter dateFromString:dayString];
NSLog(@"Day from string %@", dayFromString);
```

EDIT:

Maybe this explains why I need an NSDate object for dayFromString

```
//sepDates is a JSON array with comma separated dates i.e 13, 27, 29 of which I split it indexes so 13 is at index 0 27 at 1 and 29 at 2. May string is the string that holds the above dates
        sepDates = [mayString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

//Day string is todays date i.e 16 (16th)
        NSDate *dayFromString = [dayFormatter dateFromString:dayString];
        NSLog(@"Day from string %@", dayFromString);

        double min = [dayFromString timeIntervalSinceDate:[sepDates objectAtIndex:0]];
        NSLog(@"Min %f", min);

//I then want to calculate which of the dates in the sepDates array at index is closest to todays current day 16

        int minIndex = 0;
        for (int d = 1; d < [sepDates count]; ++d)
        {
            double currentmin = [dayFromString timeIntervalSinceDate:[sepDates objectAtIndex:d]];
            if (currentmin < min) {
                min = currentmin;
                minIndex = d;

                NSLog(@"minIndex = %d", minIndex);

            }
        }
```

Comment: what you are expecting? only date value(eg 15)??

Comment: @anil yep would be good

Comment: Why do you convert date to string and then again convert it back to Date? i just dont get it!!

Comment: @VinayakKini Perhaps it's been edited by the user in the meantime?

Comment: @VinayakKini because I want to? and need to at this point in the logic

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDateComponents* components = [calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];// Get necessary date components
[components day]; //gives you day
```

Edited as you want only date. You can set NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit| if you want year and month values too.

Comment: I tried this but I need an NSDate object so that I can do timeIntervalSinceDate i have edited my question hopefully it makes sense.

Comment: What exactly do you need timeIntervalSinceDate for? To extract timeInterval value of the day? @AlexMcPherson

Answer (score 0):

Format the `dayFromString` again using the same date formatter you will get what you are expecting

```
 NSLog(@"Date %@", [dayFormatter stringFromDate: dayFromString]);
```

But **this is not you want**. NSDateFormatter is used to format a date.

```
[dayFormatter dateFromString:dayString];
```

will return a NSDate object. If you are not providing all the values through the string it will fill up the missing values with a reference time. So the output you got is not an error. If you want to take some components(day,hour..) from a date use **NSDateComponents**. NSDateFormatter is only using for format the date.

Comment: I have edited my question dont know if this makes sense what I am trying to do.